# How can I prevent the windows command prompt to suspend the process if there's a selection?

Tags: windows, command-line

Windows command prompt has this nasty "feature". If you are running a process and accidentally start a selection by click and drag, ending up with a single character "cursor shaped" selection, the running process will suspend until the selection is cleared.

Is there a way to disable this?

Comment: Disabling Quick edit naturally helps with the accidental selections, but doesn't really answer your question. I think the process is only halted if it does screen output and that can't be disabled.

Comment: @Sami: well, that's something I guess. Please add it as an answer, so I can mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click in the CMD window's title > **Properties** > **Options** > (Uncheck) **QuickEdit mode**